# EF6 Updating database from model overwrites my DefiningQuery

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

I'm using `DefiningQuery` to specify a Read only "view" entity that contains fields from two tables, and it works great for my need.

But each time I'm updating my model (using the Model designer) and runs the "Generate Database from Model..." operation, my `DefiningQuery` is lost because the .edmx file is getting overwritten.
The SQL being generated (in the .edmx.sql file) now assumes my Read Only entity must have a corresponding table created.

Is there a way to avoid the `DefiningQuery` being overwritten when the model is updated?
If possible I would like to avoid having to generate a Database View and map to that.

A little info:

- I'm working on a project based on the Entity Framework 6.x.
- I'm using the Model First approach.
- The database is an SQL Server.